# How to extract the name of the stock in yahoo finance

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have found a code that extracts all data from the tables in the "financial" tab in yahoo finance.
Now I'll want to have the possibility to extract also the name of the stock to insert the cell A3, near to the stock symbol.

```
'this is the code to exctact the data
 Dim htm, Tr, Td, Tab1, Tab2, HTML_Content As Object
 Dim Web_URL As String
 Dim Column_Num_To_Start, iRow, iCol, eCol, iTable As Integer
 Dim Val, varVal1, varVal2, varVal3 As Variant
 Dim chtObj As ChartObject

 Column_Num_To_Start = 1
 iRow = 7
 iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
 iTable = 2

 Web_URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & Cells.Range("A2").Value & "/financials?p=" & Cells.Range("A2").Value

 Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

 With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
   .Open "GET", Web_URL, False
   .send
   HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = .responseText
 End With

 For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")
     With HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")(iTable)
         For Each Tr In .Rows
             For Each Td In Tr.Cells
             ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
             ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol) = Td.innerText
             ActiveCell.WrapText = False
             iCol = iCol + 1
             Next Td
          eCol = iCol - 1
          iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
          iRow = iRow + 1
          Next Tr
        End With
    Exit For
Next Tab1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after executing your XMLHTTP request of the page:

```
With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
   .Open "GET", Web_URL, False
   .send
   HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
```

...you can get the stock name from the header `h1`:

```
stockName = HTML_Content.getElementById("quote-header-info").getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText
```

... and then you can put it where you want (e.g. `Range("A3").Value = stockName`).

Note: I've made my test on `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SAN/financials?p=SAN`, guessing that was what your URL would have looked like.

Answer (score 2):

Across the stocks I looked at briefly it seems it is always the first h1 so you can literally use a fast css selector of

```
HTML_Content.querySelector("h1").innerText
```

You can also use an attribute = value css selector

```
HTML_Content.querySelector("[data-reactid='7']").innerText
```

As a side note of interest to some: you can use the complex class as follows:

```
HTML_Content.querySelector(".D\28 ib\29 > h1").innerText
```

Modern browsers and many libraries are optimized for css so apart from older IE versions this is a fast selection method.

I looked at S&P 500 (^GSPC), BP p.l.c. (BP.L), Banco Santander, S.A. (SAN), Apple Inc. (AAPL), General Electric Company (GE), Alcoa Corporation (AA), KOSPI Composite Index (^KS11)

Comment: I will try asap

Comment: Give it a try. It is a faster selection method.

Comment: Dear Qharr. Sorry for my late replay.
I tried your code, but I cannot receive the value.
I used the code on top and I added your code in this way:
strStock = HTML_Content.querySelector("h1").innerTex

Comment: Please pastebin.com your exact code and I will have a look. The code above was tested multiple times. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Thanks for replay.
the code is very long but Ireceives this error:
Object doesn't support this property or method